# Populate a select with ajax with ng-options using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

With angularJS, I need populate a select with data coming from a ajax call.

I have a controlller called "TabPacProfissionalController".In this controller I do a ajax call to get json data('profissionais object').
So far so good.

My problem is that I get the json data returning from server, but my select is never populate.

What am I missing here?

My ajax return is:

```
{"results":[{"nr":"8","nome":"AAAAAAAAAAAA"},
{"nr":"17","nome":"BBBBBBB"},
{"nr":"27","nome":"BBBBBAAAAA"},
,{"nr":"1004","nome":"CCCCCCCCC"}]}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="paciente.texto.sexo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Profissional:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10" ng-controller="TabPacProfissionalController as tabProfCtrl">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedProf" ng-options="nome for (nr,nome) in tabProfCtrl.profissionais">
                  <option value=''>Select an option</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('TabPacProfissionalController', function($http) {
        this.profissionais = {};
        $http.get('/getStaff?tipoProf=1').then(function(response){
                  this.profissionais=response.data.results;
                  console.log(this.profissionais.toString());
        },function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
      });
```

Comment: Add `var self = this;` and reference to `self` inside the http success function

Answer (score 1):

If you want the label to display the `nome` property and the value to be the `nr` property try the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="paciente.texto.sexo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Profissional:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" ng-controller="TabPacProfissionalController as tabProfCtrl">
        <select ng-model="tabProfCtrl.selectedProf" ng-options="profissionais.nr as profissionais.nome for profissionais in tabProfCtrl.profissionais">
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>         
    </div>
</div>
```

(key,value) notation you are using is for object data sources, as in if you wanted to iterate through the properties of a single object, rather than a collection of objects which is what you seem to be getting from the `$http` call.

To see the parsed server response, you could use `angular.fromJson(response.data)`

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Oe46ZOwGkal5SvxJPpQk?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

Comment: Sorry. It doesnt works. I get a new error: Error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'profissionais.nome for profissionais.nr in tabProfCtrl.profissionais'. Element: <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="selected" ng-options="profissionais.nome for profissionais.nr in tabProfCtrl.profissionais">

Comment: See my updated answer. I provided a plunker showing the functionality.

Comment: It doesnt works. The ajax data  returning is as I have posted above, when I see in chrome debugger networks tools. But, My console.log(this.profissionais.toString()) shows something as: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],.....

Comment: And each object is something as  {"nr":"X", "nome:","AAA"}

Comment: If you're string to see the string format of your objects, try using `JSON.stringify(response.data.results)`. I added additional display and value options to the plunker link. However, I may not be understanding the issue your having anymore. You tried the `ng-options` as demonstrated in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Oe46ZOwGkal5SvxJPpQk?p=preview) as nothing is showing? Try `angular.fromJSON()`. Also you may have an extra comma in your example after `{"nr":"27","nome":"BBBBBAAAAA"}`

Comment: Thank you. I did with JSON.stringify(response.data.results) and the result is exactly the same returning from chrome network dev tool. So, the problem is not the data. I just copied your ng-options and replace with the mine but no look.

Comment: Okay, one final attempt. Try using `angular.fromJson()` to parse the incoming content like `var response = angular.fromJson(response.data); this.profissionais = response.results;` to parse the JSON from the server. It could be an invalid format that is prevent the `<select>` from populating. The provided examples assume a valid JS collection.

Comment: I think my problem is that in my controller. If I get rid off the assignment into success function and I initialize profissionais with a static array as you used in your sample, then all works. Can you check if my controller is ok?

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander.